# How do I implement a breadth first and depth first search web crawler?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am attempting to write a web crawler in Python with Beautiful Soup in order to crawl a webpage for all of the links. After I obtain all the links on the main page, I am trying to implement a depth-first and breadth-first search to find 100 additional links. Currently, I have scraped and obtained the links on the main page. Now I need help implement the depth-first and breadth-first aspect of my crawler.

I believe my web crawler is doing a depth-first search. Is this correct or is my code not properly doing a depth-first search? Additionally, how can I adjust my code to create a breadth-first search? I believe I need to have a queue and use the pop function, but I am unsure how to correctly execute the loops as I am new to Python.

I have tried adjusting my code, but I nothing I have tried has worked thus far to get the proper result.

```
from pandas import *
import urllib.request
import re
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#open webpage and put into soup

myURL="http://toscrape.com"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(myURL)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

#get links on the main page 

websitesvisited = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    websitesvisited.append(link.get('href'))

#use depth-first search to find 100 additional links

allLinks= [] 
for links in websitesvisited:
    myURL=links
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(myURL)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    if len(allLinks) < 101:
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            if link.get('href') not in allLinks:
                if link.get('href') != None:
                    if link.get('href') [0:4] == 'http':
                        allLinks.append(link.get('href'))
    time.sleep(3)

for weblinks in allLinks:
    print(weblinks)
```

I web scraped the main page and obtained all the links. Now I am expecting to obtain around 100 additional links using depth-first and breadth-first web crawling.

Answer (score 4):

You're very much on the right track. The key to DFS is recursion, which is the missing element in the above code. For each link on the current page, recursively explore it before visiting the remaining links on the page. Use a `visited` set to keep track of which pages have already been crawled to avoid getting caught in cycles.

The "total links explored" value is likely not helpful in a DFS, because your crawler will just shoot down the first link of the first 100 pages, then head back without any breadth to it (almost every page on the internet has links, so terminal nodes are hard to come by). A "depth" (or *distance*) cap makes more sense: this allows us to explore all of the links `max_depth` pages away from the current one.

Either way, the code is mostly the same, and of course, you can say "give me the first `cap` links up to `max_depth` pages deep" if you code that up as your base case in the recursion. Another idea is ensuring all the links you're exploring are from the quotes.toscrape site. A BFS would be strict about exploring the immediate frontier and fanning out. This can be done iteratively with a queue.

Here's a recursive DFS sketch:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links_recursive(base, path, visited, max_depth=3, depth=0):
    if depth < max_depth:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base + path).text, "html.parser")

            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                href = link.get("href")

                if href not in visited:
                    visited.add(href)
                    print(f"at depth {depth}: {href}")

                    if href.startswith("http"):
                        get_links_recursive(href, "", visited, max_depth, depth + 1)
                    else:
                        get_links_recursive(base, href, visited, max_depth, depth + 1)
        except:
            pass


get_links_recursive("http://toscrape.com", "", set(["http://toscrape.com"]))
```

And here's a BFS sketch:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import deque

visited = set(["http://toscrape.com"])
dq = deque([["http://toscrape.com", "", 0]])
max_depth = 3

while dq:
    base, path, depth = dq.popleft()
    #                         ^^^^ removing "left" makes this a DFS (stack)

    if depth < max_depth:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base + path).text, "html.parser")

            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                href = link.get("href")

                if href not in visited:
                    visited.add(href)
                    print("  " * depth + f"at depth {depth}: {href}")

                    if href.startswith("http"):
                        dq.append([href, "", depth + 1])
                    else:
                        dq.append([base, href, depth + 1])
        except:
            pass
```

These are pretty minimal sketches. Error handling and pruning of hrefs is only barely dealt with. There is a mix of relative and absolute links, some of which have leading and/or trailing slashes. I'll leave manipulating those as an exercise to the reader.